# Radio button value from child to parent component - Angular

Tags: angular, radio-button, getvalue

I am working with a parent component and a child component.

I have two radio buttons, if I select “Change Title” and write a new text , the ’Original Title’ is updated with the new value. And that works fine but how can I do to restore the original title if I focus on “keep original Title” ?

[MY CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cahfwq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.css)

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to restore a variable after it's been changed?

Comment: If I write something in the input field and then choose radio button “Keep Screening” what I want to achieve is avoid that the variable change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have written you need to create a formGroup (in case of Reactive Form) and pass the value of the radio button as well as the text from child to parent. Based on those values you need to write a conditional statement in the parent component which will decide whether to change the title or not. I have created a sample code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8zvc9s). Sample created in a very short time so please cross check if performance can be enhanced. While dealing with forms try to use ReactiveForms or TemplateDrivenForms and try to use lesser **div** in the design.

Please mark it as answer if it resolves your query. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is a temp variable to store the changed value before save.

Mistakes in your code:

1. Missing change event handler for your checkbox; this helps to toggle values.

```
  handleCheckboxEvent($event) {
    const val = +$event.target.value;
    if (val) {
      this.disableTextbox = false;
      this.tempData.emit();
    } else {
      this.disableTextbox = true;
      this.boxValue = null;
      this.tempData.emit(null);
    }
  }
```

2. Missing keyup event handler / ngModel to bind the temp value to your title.

Go through the code in the [Updated Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zukfux?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and tested as requested in Question.(I tried explaining in points also as below, please let me know if any more questions.

> Below is the link of updated code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ekuykb?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts

As per my thoughts Blow are the steps:
step 1-  send **titleScreening** to child component like this: <app-child (updateDataEvent)="updateData($event)" [titleScreening]="titleScreening">
step 2- receive it in child component with @input decorater
step 3- use ngonchanges lifecyclehook to maintain previous and current value
step4: with the help of existing @output event emitter send previous value i.e original value.